# Express.js middleware function isn't getting called

Tags: javascript, express

I am using Express.js and I am having trouble routing to a middleware function that I want to get called. I have app.js, userauth.routes.js, and index.js. If the url starts with /user/, it is intended to go to a function in userauth.routes.js to verify the session. Afterwards, it is supposed to be routed to index.js. Unfortunately, it seems like the validation part is completely skipped over.

app.js:

```js
var userauthRouter = require('./routes/userauth.routes.js');
var indexRouter = require('./routes');

app.use('/user/', userauthRouter);
app.use('/', indexRouter);
```

userauth.routes.js:

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get("/*", function(req, res, next){
    console.log("user authentication");
    next();
});

module.exports = router;
```

index.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'));
});

module.exports = router;
```

At the moment, I should see `user authentication` in the output but I see nothing.

Comment: what path did you access and not get the log?

Comment: @skara9 /user/dashboard, /user/, /user/delaware, /user/connecticut

Comment: try accessing `/user/a`

Comment: @skara9 nothing

Comment: how about `/user//a`?

Comment: @skara9 nothing again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241437/discussion-between-amicharski-and-skara9).